# Orchard CMS page and custom html in footer?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm still trying to wrap my head around zones, widgets, and layers so please go easy.

I'm trying to setup a way that each content page in the admin portion of Orchard CMS can have an additional field that which custom html could be added that gets rendered in a specific spot in a custom theme.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "each content page in the admin portion" but there is an HTML field that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an html content that is different for every page, use an html field, and have your theme place it wherever you want.

If the html you want to include is the same for every page, use an html widget and place it in the zone you want it to be displayed.